# Express-Session: Where the connect.sid values comes from?

Tags: node.js, express, express-session, sessionid

Example if you run:

```
console.log('Connect.sid', req.headers.cookie);
```

Result of `connect.sid` value:

```
connect.sid=s%3A04x6YVZX68nRrhakd3SWuIMakDhuGptO.kyBVHe0HDI4pW1JeOl0xEopRYgQ51ZVlAKdfui7ii18
```

And if you log the `req.sessionID` the result is going to be this:

```
04x6YVZX68nRrhakd3SWuIMakDhuGptO
```

At the moment I have clear that the first part of the cookie session(`connect.sid`) is the sessionId. That anyone can build with the `genid` function that express-session provides us.

To be more in context, I have some WAF rules, some of those rules are for check SQL Attacks or things like that. Some times(fair away), my web application firewall (In Azure) gets fired cause match a pattern in the `connect.sid` cookie.

I need to handle whole the cookie but I'm only be able to interact with the first section of the cookie value (The sessionID). And here's where I have some questions:

- What is this second value?
- How can I handle it?
- Is possible to delete it and create a new one if the pattern match?
- Am I making a lot of trouble with this? Is it better only to add an exception to the WAF?

Just in case, I was reading this very similar question "[express-session - the difference between session id and connect.sid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56726972/express-session-the-difference-between-session-id-and-connect-sid)", but I need more detail about it.

Comment: Did you happen to find the answer to your quesions? Mainly the "what is this second value" one?

Comment: Ok, I just did - overall the whole cookie value is the result of https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-signature - prefixed with `"s:"` and then URL-encoded